# How to remove program name from "Uninstall or change a program" in windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I need to delete some listed information from Win7 64bit "Control Panel/Program/Programs and Features/Uninstall or change a program". Basically, I don't want to uninstall the program but just delete the application name listed on the panel.

Can someone show me how to do that?

Thank you

Comment: I found CCleaner Portable is good at this task. http://download.cnet.com/CCleaner-Portable/3000-18512_4-75182000.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Search your program in registry keys

```
[KHEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall]
```

Be careful with registry ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use [Revo Uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) to do that.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is quite a lengthy process that involves registry edits. There is a good guide on how to do it [here](http://www.vistax64.com/tutorials/86721-programs-features-remove-uninstall-entry.html).